# Realm Debug with Proxy in Chrome not possible

Tags: debugging, proxy, react-native, realm

I used asyncStorage from React-Native to save my data locally on a device but not wanted to switch to Realm. Everything works fine with realm as expected and the data are fetched right too. Only problem is `I cannot debug with Chrome because i am behind a proxy`

I have the issue that through systemadminrights my computer automatically always connect´s to a proxy wifi. So i have no other option than getting this (Option 2) to run.

- Option 1: Smartphone and Laptop are in the same `non-proxy` wifi (**Works**)
- Option 2: Smartphone and/or Laptop are in the `proxy` wifi (**Don't work**)

**Is there an option to add the proxy to my Realm with my user:password etc?**

I get following error Message:

[image]

Comment: I am sorry this is no actual Issue - Found out that I had two different networks on each devices - Laptop / Smartphone. As far as i have both in the same networks it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry this is no actual Issue - Found out that I had two different networks on each devices - Laptop / Smartphone. As far as i have both in the same networks it works fine